# Error While Writing into a BigQuery table from Dataproc - Spark

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, dataproc

I am trying to insert data into a Big Query table from Dataproc - Spark. I'm using the following code:

```
df.write \
  .format("bigquery") \
  .option("temporaryGcsBucket","bucket/temp") \
  .save("project.datasource.table1")
```

Error:

pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'SaveMode is set to ErrorIfExists and Table project.datasource.table1 already exists. Did you want to add data to the table by setting the SaveMode to Append? Example: df.write.format.options.mode(SaveMode.Append).save()'

I inserted ".mode(SaveMode.Append)", but It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

That will do:

```
df.write \
  .format("bigquery") \
  .option("temporaryGcsBucket","bucket/temp") \
  .mode("append") \
  .save("gcp-bankier.sof.table1")
```

Comment: df.write   .format("bigquery")   .option("temporaryGcsBucket","bucket/temp")   .save("project.datasource.table1")     .mode("append")
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'SaveMode is set to ErrorIfExists and Table project.datasource.table1 already exists. Did you want to add data to the table by setting the SaveMode to Append?

Comment: Move **mode** section before **save**. Save method does not see yet mode section so it throws error before realize that there is mode = append.

Comment: that's works. thanks a lot!